# Repeating JSON Aggregated Array with Row Limits

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have an Oracle 19 database with a JSON aggregated array which I need to cut off and repeat after a set number of rows, for example:

```
[{"personId": "13274614","surname": "SMITH"},{"personId": "13275037","surname": "JONES"}]
[{"personId": "13275038","surname": "THOMAS"},{"personId": "13275039","surname": "BAKER"}]
```

...etc. Here's some basic SQL to illustrate how my current dataset is put together:

```
    SELECT
    json_arrayagg(json_object('personId' VALUE person.id,
                              'surname'  VALUE person.surname
                              )
    RETURNING CLOB) as customer_json
    FROM
    person
```

I need to push customer data to an API endpoint. Pushing 1 customer record at a time is not performant, but the entire dataset is in the millions so cannot fit in a single array, therefore I need to, if possible, achieve the best of both worlds - 200 customer records in an array, which then ends and the next row starts a fresh array with the next 200 customers.

I have searched and found some mentions of a LIMIT function, but have not been able to successfully apply this.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT ...` to limit the number of rows inside a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT json_arrayagg(
         json_object(
           'personId' VALUE id,
           'surname'  VALUE surname
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) as customer_json
FROM   (
  SELECT id, surname
  FROM   person
  ORDER BY id
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
)
```

Before Oracle 12, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT json_arrayagg(
         json_object(
           'personId' VALUE id,
           'surname'  VALUE surname
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) as customer_json
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         surname,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM   person
)
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 1 AND 200;
```

---

If you want all the rows in 200 row groups then:

```sql
SELECT json_arrayagg(
         json_object(
           'personId' VALUE id,
           'surname'  VALUE surname
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) as customer_json
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         surname,
         CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)/200) AS grp
  FROM   person
)
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This handles the restriction element, but not the "repeating" requirement. I appreciate that I could manually set the offset for each query and have a bunch of unioned datasets, but with millions of records to process, I'd need circa 30,000 queries to achieve this. I'm looking for something that will automatically terminate an array after 200 records, then start a new one on another row.

Comment: this works perfectly! Thank you very much for taking the time to post this updated answer. Very much appreciated.